# CSS Hover and Display Inline Block not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

Problem is when I hover, the overlay affects all the items, i would like it to do one at a time, not all at once and also I can't get the display to show Inline-Block, items seem to be taking up the whole row, once it's fixe i know i will have to adjust the figcaption because ideally that would need to be centered under each image... anything helps.
THanks!

```js
const productData = document.querySelector('.wrap');

const productsOne = [{
    Name: "Almonds",
    id: 1,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Kit Kat",
    id: 2,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "PopCorn",
    id: 3,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Peanuts",
    id: 4,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Oreos",
    id: 5,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },


]

document.getElementById('productspage1').innerHTML = productsOne.map(products =>
  `
  

  <div id="${products.id}">
  <a href="${products.href}">
  <img src="${products.src}" width="260" height="195">
  <div class="text">${products.Name}</div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <center>
  <figcaption>
  <center>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox"name="${products.id}"class="single-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round">
  </span>
  </label>
  </center>
  </figcaption>
  </center>
  </div>

  `
).join('<br><br>')
```

```css
figcaption {
  left: 200%;
   
}



.wrap *{ 
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 195px;
  max-width: 260px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;

  
}
.text {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em; bottom: 0em; left: 0em; right: 0em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}



.wrap div:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}


img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}






/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
 
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #49ba14;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div id="productspage1">
    </div></div>
</html>
```

Comment: well, `.wrap div:hover` targets when you hover over `id="productspage1"` - you'll want `.wrap > div > div:hover .text {` or set a class on `<div id="${products.id}">` to make it trivial

Comment: Target the immediate children of `#productspage1` using `#productspage1 > div:hover .text` instead of `.wrap div:hover .text`, which will select all `divs` nested inside `.wrap`.

Comment: thanks! it worked! would you know why the display is coming out as a column? i would like them to be next to each other one by one, not sure why it's showing up in column form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targetting every div which has the .wrap div as an ancestor.

So this includes the oveerarching productspage1 div.

This snippet is more specific in targeting those divs that have the .wrap div as grandparent.

```js
const productData = document.querySelector('.wrap');

const productsOne = [{
    Name: "Almonds",
    id: 1,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Kit Kat",
    id: 2,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "PopCorn",
    id: 3,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Peanuts",
    id: 4,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },
  {
    Name: "Oreos",
    id: 5,
    src: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png",
    href: "https://happywellbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/HAPPY-hellbox-01.png"
  },


]

document.getElementById('productspage1').innerHTML = productsOne.map(products =>
  `
  

  <div id="${products.id}">
  <a href="${products.href}">
  <img src="${products.src}" width="260" height="195">
  <div class="text">${products.Name}</div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <center>
  <figcaption>
  <center>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox"name="${products.id}"class="single-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round">
  </span>
  </label>
  </center>
  </figcaption>
  </center>
  </div>

  `
).join('<br><br>')
```

```css
figcaption {
  left: 200%;
}

.wrap * {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 195px;
  max-width: 260px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.text {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  bottom: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  right: 0em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap>div>div:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #49ba14;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="productspage1">
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: nice, but how do i get them to be next to each other and not in a column, need them to make rows

Comment: You could look at making each one inline-block, but I'd suggest investigating CSS flex which will adjust the number on a row and space them out.